# Should publisher.on('accessDialogOpened') trigger when the user has previously given permissions?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

We are using "@opentok/client": "^2.15.10"

We are  trying to give additional visual feedback when the browser asks for microphone and camera permissions.

We based our solution on the Publisher event 'accessDialogOpened'.

This works very well in the case where the permission dialog is actually open and the user needs to act on it.

For some reason this event triggers in cases where the user has previously given permissions which causes some ux issues for us. (the dialog never actually opens in this scenario)

Eventually a subsequent event 'accessDialogClosed' follows after roughly 500ms which remedies the problem but still we have an undesired flicker.

My question "Is this expected and I should find a way around it? Is this a bug which can be fixed in a followup releases?"

Comment: Hi Christos, I was wondering if you could fix this issue. Got the same problem with opentok/client@2.22.1

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the exact issue and it's working fine for me now, there was some slight mistake for which there is [this](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/publish-stream/js/#access_allowed) workaround.

```
Wrong-> accessDialogClosed, function (event) { // The Allow/Deny dialog box is closed. } });

Correction--> accessDialogClosed: function (event) { // The Allow/Deny dialog box is closed. } });
```

Hope it helps!